# why can perf lead to load balancing

Tags: linux, performance, caching, load-balancing, perf

when I run my program by `./example 8388608 0 16`
there are a total of 16 threads
and I time each of them
the result is follow

```
32ms
30ms
30ms
38ms
39ms
35ms
43ms
42ms
42ms
39ms
40ms
35ms
41ms
39ms
33ms
37ms
```

The slowest thread is nearly 1.5 times the fastest one
and I use `perf stat -B -e LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores,LLC-store-misses,LLC-prefetches ./example 8388608 0 16` to record their cache-miss and their time is more balancing like

```
25ms
31ms
31ms
30ms
30ms
30ms
30ms
29ms
30ms
30ms
30ms
29ms
29ms
29ms
31ms
31ms
```

I want to know how perf runs cache counting, and also why using perf can lead to load balancing

Comment: and my cpu is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8468 CPU @2.10GHz

Comment: The multithreading scheduling I use is tbb::parallel_for

Comment: `perf` itself is running for a tiny amount of time before it forks+execs the program you tell it to start; perhaps that helps warm up the CPU frequency, so the threads get started closer to the same time if the core running the main thread is running faster?  I also wondered if `perf stat` could create extra interrupts that give the kernel more chance to reschedule threads, but no, 30 ms is way too short for PMU in counter mode to overflow, not trying to do statistical sampling.

Comment: Without a [mcve] or any info on what your threads do, it's hard to guess what might be going on here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.